# How to overwrite macro definition in CMake

Tags: c++, dll, cmake, dllimport, dllexport

I am on Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015. Suppose I am building library A with CMakeLists looking like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(A)

set(DLLIMPORT "__declspec(dllimport)")
set(DLLEXPORT "__declspec(dllexport)")

set(PROJECT_SRCS
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/TestA.cpp)

set(PROJECT_INCS
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/TestA.h)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${PROJECT_SRCS} ${PROJECT_INCS})

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE
                          WINDOWS_DLL_API=${DLLIMPORT})

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
                          WINDOWS_DLL_API=${DLLEXPORT})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
                          $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
                          $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include>)
```

I am defining the macro `WINDOWS_DLL_API` as `dllexport` when it's building library A, and defining `WINDOWS_DLL_API` as `dllimport` for external applications that is linking library A. The problem is when I have another library B that is also linking A, I don't know how to overwrite `WINDOWS_DLL_API` back to `dllexport`. Below is my attempt of my CMakeLists for library B,

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(B)

set(DLLEXPORT "__declspec(dllexport)")

set(PROJECT_SRCS
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/TestB.cpp)

set(PROJECT_INCS
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/TestB.h)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${PROJECT_SRCS} ${PROJECT_INCS})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include>)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} A)

# does not work
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
                          WINDOWS_DLL_API=${DLLEXPORT})
```

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: `... defining WINDOWS_DLL_API as dllimport for external applications that is linking library A.` - `B` is "external" library, which links with `A`, so it obtains this definition. If this definition isn't needed for `B`, simply do not define it for `A` as *INTERFACE*.

Comment: @Tsyvarev If I don't define it, then if I have an application (`add_executable`) that links to A and includes `TestA.h` , `WINDOWS_DLL_API ` will be undefined.

Comment: This might be useful [GenerateExportHeader](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/GenerateExportHeader.html). It works with `_dllexport/__dllimport`, and it also handles GCC builds with `-fvisibility=hidden`

Comment: @Nazar554 No it doesn't work with dllimport and you are forced to dllexport everything in the header. See https://blog.kitware.com/create-dlls-on-windows-without-declspec-using-new-cmake-export-all-feature/. Unfortunately dll macros are still needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Concept* of *INTERFACE* option for command `target_compile_definitions` (and for other `target_*` CMake commands) is to enforce something for **all users** of the library, both *executables* and *libraries*.

Intention to **clear** enforcement for **at least single** library's user means that the conception is **used in a wrong way**. And other approaches should be used instead.

In given case, you need to use *different* macro names for libraries `A` and `B`. And it is better to remove *INTERFACE* option completely, so even non-CMake users of your library will be happy.

**TestA.h**:

```
#ifdef BUILD_A
#define WINDOWS_DLL_API_A __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define WINDOWS_DLL_API_A __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

...
WINDOWS_DLL_API_A void foo(void);
...
```

**TestB.h**:

```
#ifdef BUILD_B
#define WINDOWS_DLL_API_B __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define WINDOWS_DLL_API_B __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// Assume usage of A is here.
#include <TestA.h>
...
WINDOWS_DLL_API_B void bar(void);
```

**A/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(A)

...    

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ...)

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "BUILD_${PROJECT_NAME}=1")
```

**B/CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(B)

...    

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ...)

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE "BUILD_${PROJECT_NAME}=1")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} A)
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39231971/3440745), which provides more detailed header, which works on Windows platforms too.

---

Note, that when the library `B` includes header from `A`, it treats `foo()` as *imported*, and this is correct: the function is defined in `A`, not in `B`. With your approach (even if you would manage to redefine `WINDOWS_DLL_API` for `B`), library `B` would incorrectly treat `foo()` as *exported*.

This is an advantage of the *conception*: **intention to overcome a *conception* signals that you do something wrong**.

Comment: wow, this works but it's more messier then I expected, not to mention that if I want my code to compile on linux I have to add a few more conditions to make `WINDOWS_DLL_API` equals to nothing.

Comment: Yes, header files become more complex if need to support several platforms(OSes). See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39231971/3440745) (I have added this reference into my post too).

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add my piece of code I'm using (compatible with CMake versions prior to 2.8.12).

In my root `CMakeLists.txt` file I have:

```
if (MSVC)
    add_definitions(-DWINDOWS_DLL_API=__declspec\(dllexport\))
else()
    add_definitions(-DWINDOWS_DLL_API=)
endif()
```

In the (sub-)project's `CMakeLists.txt` using the DLL I've put:

```
if (MSVC)
    remove_definitions(-DWINDOWS_DLL_API=__declspec\(dllexport\))
    add_definitions(-DWINDOWS_DLL_API=__declspec\(dllimport\))
endif()
```

The `MSVC` checks are necessary in my case because I also cross-compile.

**Reference**

- [CMake - override compile flags for single files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638408/cmake-override-compile-flags-for-single-files)

Comment: Just want to point out that the reason that the new `target_compile_definitions` is preferred is because the old `add_definitions` way would not work when exporting targets