# cmake does not override set variable from command line

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using a variable that I want the user to be able to pass using the command line. However, the variable is not overridden as I was expecting. The reference doc I am using is [Cmake Cache](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/CMake%20Cache.html)

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23.0)

project(design_principles)

set(PRINCIPLE "solid/single_responsibility" CACHE STRING "Enter the principle to be run" FORCE)

message(${PRINCIPLE})

add_executable(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${PRINCIPLE}.cpp
    )

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
```

The command I am passing through the command line is

```
cmake -S . -B build -DPRINCIPLE=temp
```

However, it appears that the build is always using the default value from `CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overwrite macro definition in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41866614/how-to-overwrite-macro-definition-in-cmake)

Comment: _Why_ did you use `FORCE`?

Comment: @tkausl The document mentioned this about the `FORCE` option.

 "The FORCE option will cause the set command to override and change the cache value of a variable."

Comment: Yeah, so? Thats exactly what you don't want.

Comment: Ah. See. I think I misunderstood the `FORCE` option from the docs. I thought it to mean that the user-defined value will be forced to over-ride the existing cache variable value. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html):

> Since cache entries are meant to provide user-settable values this does not overwrite existing cache entries by default. Use the `FORCE` option to overwrite existing entries. [...] If the cache entry does not exist prior to the call or the `FORCE` option is given then the cache entry will be set to the given value.

The problem is clear: since you have written `FORCE`, the `set()` command will always overwrite the cache entry. The solution is to simply get rid of `FORCE`:

```
set(PRINCIPLE "solid/single_responsibility" 
    CACHE STRING "Enter the principle to be run")
```